# Storing and checking a boolean in a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, boolean

So I was trying to create an object which basically has a constructor that takes two coordinates, `xcoord` and `ycoord`. I further created methods which shift the coordinates and I have to check if the point is valid or not(criteria for validity is if the coordinates are out of a specified range it should return `False` else `True`).

#### Problem:

My class only returns the validity for the initial points, not the shifted points.

What do I need to correct my code?

#### Code:

```
class Point:
    MaxScreenSize=10
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.xcoord=x
        self.ycoord=y
        if 0>self.xcoord or self.xcoord>Point.MaxScreenSize or 0>self.ycoord or self.ycoord>Point.MaxScreenSize:
            Point.isValidPt=False
        else:
            Point.isValidPt=True
    def translateX(self,shiftX):
        self.xcoord=self.xcoord+shiftX
    def translateY(self,shiftY):
        self.ycoord=self.ycoord+shiftY
```

#### Test Code:

I tried my code and it only returns the `isValidFunction` variable for my initial points (gives me `True` instead of `False` for following code)

```
p=Point(9,2) 
p.translateX(20)
p.translateY(10)
p.isValidPt
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `isValidPt` is only calculated when the class is instantiated. Instead try something like:

#### Code:

```
class Point:
    MaxScreenSize = 10

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xcoord = x
        self.ycoord = y

    def translateX(self, shiftX):
        self.xcoord = self.xcoord + shiftX

    def translateY(self, shiftY):
        self.ycoord = self.ycoord + shiftY

    @property
    def isValidPt(self):
        return (
            0 <= self.xcoord <= Point.MaxScreenSize and
            0 <= self.ycoord <= Point.MaxScreenSize
        )
```

#### Test Code:

```
p = Point(9, 2)
p.translateX(20)
p.translateY(10)
print(p.isValidPt)
```

#### Result:

```
False
```

Comment: Is there a way I can store a boolean variable called isValidPt? I have been instructed to store a boolean variable

Comment: Rename the method with a `_` in front, and then any place you change the  object (ie: `translateX` and `translateY`) do `self.isValidPt = self._isValidPt`

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is used basically for initiate the values. In your case the constructor checks the initial value and set  the validate flag. ie, `isValidPt`.
It will be True for the scope of `p` object you created. So you have to create  a validate function and call the validate function on both **init** and shift functions.
Check the following

```
class Point:
    MaxScreenSize=10
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.xcoord=x
        self.ycoord=y
        self.validate()

    def validate(self):
        if 0>self.xcoord or self.xcoord>Point.MaxScreenSize or 0>self.ycoord or self.ycoord>Point.MaxScreenSize:
            Point.isValidPt=False
        else:
            Point.isValidPt=True

    def translateX(self,shiftX):
        self.xcoord=self.xcoord+shiftX
        self.validate()
    def translateY(self,shiftY):
        self.ycoord=self.ycoord+shiftY
        self.validate()
```

in the above code each time the validation will perform and update the values
of `isValidPt`.